# I want to find a specific string from a file depending on its next line

Tags: bash, oracle

File contains below data and I want to find listnername and print the same. I tried to use grep command but in this case I'll not knowing the listner name. I need to find it from below file.

```
SID_LIST_DB_NAME =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = DB_NAME)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle12.2.0/app)
    )
  )

Listnername =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = abc.tdk.dk)(PORT = 1000))
    )
  )
```

Comment: No effort given?

Comment: Have you tried using xargs and dynamically setting the value for grep?

Comment: So `grep "Listnername" file.txt` doesn't work?

Comment: [Viewing Listener Configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-83323247-58C9-4CC7-9816-C3511A88A6AF.htm#ADMQS043)

Comment: *I want to find listnername and print the same* not sure what that means.

Comment: @jared_mamrot  I don't have listner name with me. I need to find it.  As suggested by oracle team it comes before (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = abc.tdk.dk)(PORT = 1000))
    )
  )
So how I can find the text which comes before the given text.

Comment: @Divya, a `grep` code was given by @jared_mamrot already, Is that not good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example and comments, it sounds like you want to search for the line `(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = abc.tdk.dk)(PORT = 1000))`, then print the 3 lines before it including `Listnername =`. Is this right? If this is what you want to do, the `grep -B` option should do the trick (https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).

E.g. if the file with the details is called "file.txt":

```
grep -B3 "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = abc.tdk.dk)(PORT = 1000))" file.txt
#Listnername =
#  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
#    (DESCRIPTION =
#      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = abc.tdk.dk)(PORT = 1000))
```

Then, to get the `Listnername =` line only, you can use `sed` to print the first line, e.g.

```
grep -B3 "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = abc.tdk.dk)(PORT = 1000))" file.txt | sed -n '1p'
#Listnername =
```

Then, if your text is "Listername = xxyyzz" and want to get rid of the "Listername =" and keep the value "xxyyzz", you could use:

```
grep -B3 "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = abc.tdk.dk)(PORT = 1000))" file.txt | sed -n 's/Listnername\ =\ \([[:alnum:]].*\)/\1/p'
#xxyyzz
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#! /bin/bash

{
  cat |
    sed -n '/^Listnername/,/^$/p' |
    tr $'\n' ' ' |
    sed -n 's/.*HOST = \([^)]*\).*PORT = \([^)]*\).*/\1:\2/p'
  echo
} <<EOF
SID_LIST_DB_NAME =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = DB_NAME)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle12.2.0/app)
    )
  )

Listnername =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = abc.tdk.dk)(PORT = 1000))
    )
  )
EOF
```

- `sed -n '/^Listnername/,/^$/p'` prints all lines between a line starting with "Listnername" and an empty line.
- `tr $'\n' ' '` replaces all newline characters with spaces.
- `sed -n 's/.*HOST = \([^)]*\).*PORT = \([^)]*\).*/\1:\2/p'` extracts the strings followed by `HOST` and `PORT` followed by an equal sign.